# non cpu profiled classes incrementing in the JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

when I profiled one of our running JVMs, I found non profiled CPU classes count is growing constantly. Even though these non profiled CPU classes are not included in the filter settings, does increase in count alarm some kind of leak? We are using some third party libraries also in our application. Right now I see the classes count is increasing in this third party library. May be we are not handling code properly? I'm not sure. Can you someone please advise if this is some kind of leak? Attached classes screenshot and related information with the third party class.
[Screen1](https://www.dropbox.com/home/FILTEC%20Team%20Folder/New%20Release?preview=Non_CPU_profiled_classes.PNG)
[Screen2](https://www.dropbox.com/home/FILTEC%20Team%20FolderNew%20Release?preview=Classes_org_mozilla_javascript_gen_count_313989.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Class loaders" probe in the "JEE & Probes" section to see which classes are loaded and what triggers the loading of those classes. The "Events" tab of that probe will show you single class loading events with stack traces.